# Producer-Consumer Problem with 2 processes in Java

Tags: java, operating-system

I got task from my professor related to Producer-Consumer problem.
The task is implement Producer-Consumer process, but

1. first process should increase its value by 5 each time
2. second process should divide its value by 2 each time.
   I found some examples of code, but nothing about multiple processes. Here is one of them.

--

```
// Java program to implement solution of producer 
// consumer problem. 

import java.util.LinkedList; 

public class Threadexample { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws InterruptedException 
    { 
        // Object of a class that has both produce() 
        // and consume() methods 
        final PC pc = new PC(); 

        // Create producer thread 
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                try { 
                    pc.produce(); 
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 

        // Create consumer thread 
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                try { 
                    pc.consume(); 
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 

        // Start both threads 
        t1.start(); 
        t2.start(); 

        // t1 finishes before t2 
        t1.join(); 
        t2.join(); 
    } 

    // This class has a list, producer (adds items to list 
    // and consumber (removes items). 
    public static class PC { 

        // Create a list shared by producer and consumer 
        // Size of list is 2. 
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(); 
        int capacity = 2; 

        // Function called by producer thread 
        public void produce() throws InterruptedException 
        { 
            int value = 0; 
            while (true) { 
                synchronized (this) 
                { 
                    // producer thread waits while list 
                    // is full 
                    while (list.size() == capacity) 
                        wait(); 

                    System.out.println("Producer produced-"
                                    + value); 

                    // to insert the jobs in the list 
                    list.add(value++); 

                    // notifies the consumer thread that 
                    // now it can start consuming 
                    notify(); 

                    // makes the working of program easier 
                    // to understand 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        // Function called by consumer thread 
        public void consume() throws InterruptedException 
        { 
            while (true) { 
                synchronized (this) 
                { 
                    // consumer thread waits while list 
                    // is empty 
                    while (list.size() == 0) 
                        wait(); 

                    // to retrive the ifrst job in the list 
                    int val = list.removeFirst(); 

                    System.out.println("Consumer consumed-"
                                    + val); 

                    // Wake up producer thread 
                    notify(); 

                    // and sleep 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
Producer produced-0
Producer produced-1
Consumer consumed-0
Consumer consumed-1
Producer produced-2
```

I am not sure if I understand my task completely. Is it possible to implement given task on this code? I want you to give me some suggestions or any sources, so I can understand what to do.
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem from your description, you should change the field's value from two threads. You would like to create a class-level field and two synchronized methods for changing his value after that create two threads and call from them both operations alternately. I think you can write that:

```
    public class Solution0 {

    private volatile int count;

    public synchronized void increment() throws InterruptedException {
        count = count + 5;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        notifyAll();
        wait();
    }

    public synchronized void divide() throws InterruptedException {
        count = count / 2;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        notifyAll();
        wait();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution0 solution = new Solution0();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true){
                    solution.increment();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true){
                    solution.divide();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Also, you can change the type of field `count` from `int` to `double`, if you need a real number.

Comment: Oh, thanks you very much! I think this one is correct

Comment: I am sorry, should I run this file standalone or implement to the first code?

Comment: This example has a "main" method so you can create jar archive from that and run it by "java -example.jar"

Comment: Im sorry for idiot questions, but is it possible to run it in online compiler? I tried to create jar archive but getting errors like "no main manifest atribute" and other :c